# regarding argument passing through shell script issue

Tags: linux, shell

Am new to shell script.

my requirement is i have a test.sh shell script file i dont know how to pass args through shell script also.

i my shell script i want o get some of the data via args like

```
perzonalize browser='FF'
```

i tried `$ test.sh perzonalize browser='FF'`
and inside script
i did

```
      echo $1 $2
```

but it prints like `perzonalize browser=FF` .i need that quote `browser='FF'`

How it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting is very critical in shell scripts.

You need to call your script as:

```
perzonalize "browser='FF'"
```

And echo 1st argument as:

```
echo "$1"
```

which will print string with single quotes:

```
browser='FF'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$@"
```

Is probably what you want.  It passes each argument along separately. According to the man page:*"$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ... **

The important thing is the double quotes.  You should almost always expand your shell veriables "$like_this".  For some rare cases you want

```
echo "$*"
```

This will produce just one string consisting of all your original arguments together, separated by whitespace.